# Restrict the file type and total size of files uploded using drag and drop option of jquery fileupload plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Jquery and I am using [blueimp jquery.fileupload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)  to upload files . In my application there is restriction for only certain type of file like .class, .java etc.

so how to specify to restrict only certain type of files and allow all the other types of file to upload ? also i have to specify the maximum size of all the files getting uploded not individual size but the sum of sizes of all the file should be restricted.

I have implemented these two things for add file button in that plugin.but i am not able to implement this with drag and drop option provided in that plugin.

Code is like :

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
            disableImageResize: false,
            maxFileSize: 5000000,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|txt)$/i
  });
```

So it is like max size for each item and file types which are accepted.
I want to specify the type to be restricted and maximum size of all files tobe restricted

Comment: not really an answer to you question but can I suggest an alternative?  http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, not all browsers support files size restriction - some only support names and not any additional data.

Now, to the question at hand - use the callbacks the plugin provides.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
        add: function (e, result) { 
            // Here you can access properties like:
            // var type = result.files[0].type;
            // var size = result.files[0].size;
            // and so on........            
        }
});
```

You should check the [callbacks API](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options)

Comment: It's good but problem with this is :- > 1. in callback add method,if i done the validation part,how to pass the control to upload the file. 2.If i set autoUploadfile to true then it doesnt show the user options to start/cancel the uploading of file and directly upload the files

Comment: 1. Use `result.submit()`.  
2. So don't. Decide what to upload and when on your own.  
3. ...  
4. PROFIT!
  
JK. Good luck.

Comment: ok .I ll surely try this .Thanks a lot.Struck on this from long time.

Comment: Hope you'll get it. Good luck.

Comment: Yup Thanks. I'll reply on this if i face any problem

Comment: No,after using result.submit(),it is still getting uploded automatically.is any any function like drop the file and allow user to start the uploading.

Comment: Try adding `autoUpload: false` to the `fileupload` options.

Comment: it is already set to false. Can you tell me one thing. when i use this call back method.it's doesnt call the script written below.I m not getting how to call that.I tried everythng.how to return from that callback.

Comment: There is no return from the callback. You can just not call `.submit()` or `.process()`. You could save all the objects somewhere else (a global variable, perhaps), and upload them all the moment the user clicks a button.

Comment: Ohhk. Can u tell me does this AcceptFileType parameter accepts regular expression like negation of the filetype which should be restricted and then other from that all the file type will be accepted. I am trying so many reg exp which is working fine in all other places.but not here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35009/discussion-between-irunner-and-ezslaver)